# Automatic root privileges when the computer starts

Tags: macos

I want to use `atMonitor` to monitor (CPU, memory, networks, etc.) what is going on in my computer (MacBook Pro). I know how to automatically start atMonitor when may laptop starts, but I have this error:

`atMonitor 2.7.1 helper process does not have root priviledges`

How can I give the root privileges (or lesser) to a software when it starts?

Btw, does it have to be root privileges for monitoring? Could it be something lesser in order to let the software do monitoring without being able to do something definitely bad in case of a malware embedded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. The clue is in the error message: the helper program needs root permissions. For some reason, it had it on my old computer, but it no longer had it after I transferred it via TimeMachine to my new one. The solution is:

- open the terminal
- login as an administrator (I have a special account for that)
- cd to atMonitor.app/Contents, e.g. cd /Applications/Utilities/atMonitor.app/Contents
- Run: sudo chmod u+s Resources/atMonitorHelper
- Type the account's password when required.

The chmod step sets root permissions on the atMonitorHelper, regardless who launches it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I gave up on atMonitor and I installed the multi-cpu version of MenuMeters.